# How to hide menu item from high level roles but show for low level

Tags: 7, routes, users

I have 3 roles on site:

1. anonymous user
2. authenticated user
3. admin

I created a new page:

```
function learning_menu()
{
    $items = array();

    $items['learning'] = array(
        'page callback'    => 'learning_output',
        'access callback' => 'learning_access',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        );

    return $items;
}
```

I manually created a menu item for this page in the top menu. This item should be displayed only for authenticated users, but not admins. Unfortunately, admin as also an authenticated user. So I had to use a trick to disallow access to this page to admins using this access callback:

```
function learning_access()
{
    global $user;

    $n = count($user->roles);
    if ($n === 1)
    {
        $data = array_values($user->roles);
        if ($data[0] === 'authenticated user')
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

It works but when I uploaded this module to server, I was unable to manually add a menu item for this page. Because admin doesn't have access to it.

How can I allow an admin to access this page? In the same time the menu item shouldn't be shown for him.

Comment: Then you can do another thing, remove 'access callback', but in the page callback function write your condition and make drupal_access_denied for admin user

Comment: @Nagarjuna In this case the menu item will be shown.

Comment: hmm yaa.. but this some thing like deadlock situation. Hide that Menu using https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility

Comment: @Nagarjuna This module won't help. Because even if I just tick authenticated user, it will still show for the admin. Because admin is an authenticated user.

Comment: @Nagarjuna I think, the only way is to attach a hook to the function that generates menu and check this item there.

Comment: why cant u directly hide 'admin' user using that module? Jus curious..

Comment: @Nagarjuna I don't see, where it allows to hide the item for a role. It just allows to show.

Comment: Then Can you give a shot on this module https://www.drupal.org/project/roles_for_menu or https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_per_role

Comment: @Nagarjuna Roles for menu module worked. Please, post it as an answer so I could close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion above,

Remove `'access callback' => 'learning_access',` add `drupal_access_denied()` in page call back

```
function learning_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['learning'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'learning_output',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}



function learning_output() {
  global $user;

  $n = count($user->roles);
  if ($n === 1) {
    $data = array_values($user->roles);
    if ($data[0] === 'authenticated user') {
      drupal_access_denied();
    } else {
      //YOUR code Here      
    }
  }
}
```

And Use [Roles for Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/roles_for_menu) module to hide the `learning` menu.

> This module allows you to restrict access to menu items based on user
>   roles. It is used when you don't want to copy your whole menu just
>   because for one specific role you want to hide one menu item.
>
> The module will add a fieldset with options for restricting access or
>   gaining access to menu link for a specific role/roles

Comment: No need to add access_denied into the page callback. I added `'access arguments' => array('access content'),` into the menu item.

Comment: Cool Cheers. :)